# Is it only possible to have 1 Auction House per account?

Tags: solana, metaplex

I created an Auction House: `BkGWsACjXyrxSwqATi8rJzmCbhmTAcjCodBMgfC1pGu2` on devnet on this account: `4xRGFpvEfPF7NBZjZjAh8NMKtXkwNHBwvh3i2oWyNxdG`.

When I try to run `create_auction_house` again to create a new one, I get an error with the following log:

```
    logs: [
    'Program hausS13jsjafwWwGqZTUQRmWyvyxn9EQpqMwV1PBBmk invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: CreateAuctionHouse',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Allocate: account Address { address: BkGWsACjXyrxSwqATi8rJzmCbhmTAcjCodBMgfC1pGu2, base: None } already in use',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x0',
    'Program hausS13jsjafwWwGqZTUQRmWyvyxn9EQpqMwV1PBBmk consumed 18536 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program hausS13jsjafwWwGqZTUQRmWyvyxn9EQpqMwV1PBBmk failed: custom program error: 0x0'
]
```

As it says that the previous AH is already in use, is it possible to setup a new one on the same account?

Comment: This is quite specific and needs some more information to properly answer.  Based on what you're showing though, `CreateAuctionHouse` calls `Allocate` on the auction house account, so you can't redo `CreateAuctionHouse` on the same address. You'll probably need to configure the existing auction house.

Comment: I understand that, and that is what I'm wondering. Ideally there should be a way to `CreateAuctionHouse` for one address. I don't know what more information I can provide than what I've already given above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have multiple auction houses per single creator wallet.

HOWEVER, it is only possible to have one auction house for a combination of (creator wallet + treasury mint id).

There is a reason for this.

Specifically, the auction house key is a PDA calculated from the combination of creator wallet and treasury mint id. The static method to calculate the PDA can be found on the AuctionHouseProgram class in the SDK:

AuctionHouseProgram.findAuctionHouseAddress

You can see that the above method takes two arguments, i.e. the creator wallet id and the treasury mint id.

Being a PDA guarantees that auction house public key is unique for each combination of creator wallet and treasury mint id. That is the reason each wallet can only have one auction house per treasury mint.