# How to make an auction with the new metaplex js sdk?

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

I am working on building a solana marketplace and trying to update from the old solana marketplace to auction house.

**code:**

```
    const authority = metaplex.identity();

      const auctionHouse = await metaplex
        .auctions()
        .createAuctionHouse({
          sellerFeeBasisPoints: 200,
          requiresSignOff: false,
          treasuryMint: WRAPPED_SOL_MINT,
          authority: authority.publicKey,
          canChangeSalePrice: true,
          feeWithdrawalDestination: publicKey,
          treasuryWithdrawalDestinationOwner: publicKey,
        })
        .run();



 

 
  const listNft = async () => {
    try {
      const NFTs = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner(publicKey).run();
      console.log(NFTs[4].mintAddress.toString(), " nft");
      const auctionHouse = await metaplex
        .auctions()
        .findAuctionHouseByCreatorAndMint(publicKey, WRAPPED_SOL_MINT)
        .run();

      const listtx = metaplex
        .auctions()
        .builders()
        .createListing({
          mintAccount: NFTs[4].mintAddress,
          price: lamports(1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL),
          auctionHouse: auctionHouse,
        });
      var rpcClient = await metaplex.rpc().sendTransaction(listtx);
      console.log(rpcClient, "listed nft");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const getListing = async () => {
    const NFTs = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner(publicKey).run();
    const retrievedAuctionHouse = await metaplex
      .auctions()
      .findAuctionHouseByCreatorAndMint(publicKey, WRAPPED_SOL_MINT)
      .run();
    console.log(retrievedAuctionHouse?.address?.toString(), "auction pubkey");
    const retrieveListing = await metaplex
      .auctions()
      .for(retrievedAuctionHouse)
      .findListingByAddress(NFTs[4].mintAddress)
      .run();

    console.log(retrieveListing, "retrieving listings");
  };

  const bidNft = async () => {
    const NFTs = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner(publicKey).run();
    const auctionHouse = await metaplex
      .auctions()
      .findAuctionHouseByCreatorAndMint(publicKey, WRAPPED_SOL_MINT)
      .run();
    const { bid, buyerTradeState } = await metaplex
      .auctions()
      .for(auctionHouse)
      .bid({
        mintAccount: NFTs[5].mintAddress,
        price: lamports(0.5 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL),
      });
    console.log(bid, buyerTradeState, "bidding");
  };
```

**errors:**

**when trying to list nft:**

MetaplexError: AuctionHouseProgram > Account is already initialized"

> > Source: Program > AuctionHouseProgram [hausS13jsjafwWwGqZTUQRmWyvyxn9EQpqMwV1PBBmk]
> > Problem: The program [AuctionHouseProgram] at address [hausS13jsjafwWwGqZTUQRmWyvyxn9EQpqMwV1PBBmk] raised an error of code [1] that translates to "Account is already initialized"".
> > Solution: Check the error message provided by the program.

Caused By: TokenLendingError#AlreadyInitialized: Account is already initialized"

```
at RpcClient.parseProgramError (RpcClient.mjs?e98e:206:1)
at RpcClient.sendTransaction (RpcClient.mjs?e98e:48:1)
```

**When trying to fetch listings:**

Account.mjs?9f45:47 Uncaught (in promise) MetaplexError: Account Not Found

> > Source: SDK
> > Problem: The account of type [ListingReceipt] was not found at the provided address [3m517hu6UuV5HjdLmb2GxZkttKTtQ8VseHRCPuUTDJmz].
> > Solution: Ensure the provided address is correct and that an account exists at this address.

```
at assertAccountExists (Account.mjs?9f45:47:1)
at eval (Account.mjs?9f45:39:1)
at Object.handle (findListingByAddress.mjs?1810:23:44)
at async eval (Task.mjs?1340:58:1)
at async Disposable.run (Disposable.mjs?b308:22:1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a way around

1. Instead of using metaplex.auction().builder().createListing i used metaplex.auctions().for(auctionHouse).list().
2. Then funded the auction fee payer account which is a pda.
3. Finally in findListingByAddress i passed the sellerTradeState

   ```
   const { listing, sellerTradeState } = await metaplex
   .auctions()
   .for(auctionHouse)
   .list({
     mintAccount: NFTs[1].mintAddress,
     price: sol(1.5),
   })
   .run();
   ```

For fetching the listed nft

```
const retrieveListing = await metaplex
  .auctions()
  .for(retrievedAuctionHouse)
  .findListingByAddress(
    sellerTradeState
  )
  .run();
```

Comment: The library seems to have changed since you responded.  I am wondering if you have this working with the latest @metaplex-foundation/js library. I am struggling with all sorts of errors trying to list an NFT to a newly created auctionhouse.

Answer (score 0):

Just from the information provided above, there are two issues:

1. You might have run the `createAuctionHouse` instruction already once which created the Auction house and now that you are running the `listNft` function which also runs `createAuctionHouse` instruction, it throws an `Account already exists` error. You can see why this happens here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72808405/19264629
2. You are using the NFTs mint address in `findListingByAddress` instruction, which is wrong. You have to create a ListingReceipt as stated here: https://docs.metaplex.com/guides/auction-house/#auction-house-receipts while creating the listing itself (this needs to be done in one single transaction). Once this is done, you need to plugin the receipt address in the `findListingByAddress` to fetch the listings.

Comment: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js/blob/main/packages/js/test/plugins/auctionHouseModule/createListing.test.ts

Comment: Is it posiible to use the above test?

Comment: for #1 : Interestingly, createListing method expects an auction house (mandatory) param, which means we first have to create one and pass it as a param while creating a listing - so not sure how to createListing without auction house first being created? :(

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work.  The trick was to fund the auction house "Fee Account"  as explained above and in  [Auction House CLI: I cannot execute the sale instruction to list my NFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834999/auction-house-cli-i-cannot-execute-the-sale-instruction-to-list-my-nft)

```
const ah = await mx
        .auctionHouse()
        .findByAddress({ address:ahKey })
        .run();

const nft = await mx
        .nfts()
        .create({
            name:"TESTNFT",
            symbol: "TESTNFT",
            uri: "https://blah.com",
            sellerFeeBasisPoints : 100,
            creators: [
                {
                    address: wallet.publicKey,
                    share: 100,
                }]
        })
        .run();

    const price = sol(0.1);

const { listing, sellerTradeState } = await mx
        .auctionHouse()
        .list({
            auctionHouse: ah,
            mintAccount: nft.mintAddress,
            price
        })
        .run()
```